# Alfresco ADF login issue

Tags: angularjs, alfresco, yeoman, alfresco-share, ecm

I'm currently trying to get along with the Alfresco development environment but after installing properly Alfresco ECM, I'm stuck after having generated the demo app with yeoman.
I can't find the password despite that I've always put admin/admin in anything I've installed.
[Alfresco ADF login page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/swjmb.jpg)

Moreover when I generate an app from the github repository demos like the datatable for instance,
[Files from the ng2-component datatable demo](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cnN2L.jpg)

It doesn't give me anything when I start it just a blank page at localhost:63621

I sincerely hope that anyone can help to resolve those issues which I believe may be linked.

P.S : besides that, everything works properly, the Share webapp works perfectly(I can log in with the users I created in it), even BPM (Activiti) that i wanted to try.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a couple of things that you can check:

- If you are executing the FE and BE from different domains try to follow this guide:
  https://community.alfresco.com/external-link.jspa?url=https%3A%2F%2Fgithub.com%2FAlfresco%2Falfresco-ng2-components%2Fblob%2Fmaster%2FALFRESCOCORS.md
- check the url it the settings for the Content service and Prcess service are correct.